How to prevent automatic kernel subnet routing in Centos 7?
I'm using Centos 7 as a firewall by iptables and iproute2 routing rules.
My server has:

Three VLAN interfaces: VLAN10, VLAN20, VLAN30
Two custom routing tables: 100 and 200 in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
IP addresses corresponding to the VLAN interfaces:

192.168.10.0/24
192.168.20.0/24
192.168.30.0/24



My goal is to place all of the routings in the custom routing tables, leaving the main on empty. I use only static routes in the specific tables without a default one, and It works well. Even if I remove the subnet routes and places them in the correct route-interfacename files with correct routing tables, they show up again in the main table after the next reboot.
ip route show table main

192.168.10.0/24 dev VLAN10 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.254 metric 400
192.168.20.0/24 dev VLAN20 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.254 metric 401
192.168.30.0/24 dev VLAN30 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.30.254 metric 402

How can I move permanently these subnet routes to my custom routing tables?
Thank you in advance.

A route defined by the network prefix (determined from address and netmask and corresponds to the part of the address where all bits in the netmask are 1) is called a prefix route and it is added by the kernel if netmask is not /32 (single address). To prevent the addition of the prefix route by the kernel when assigning an address to an interface, use noprefixroute flag.
For example:
# ip addr add noprefixroute 192.168.5.5/24 dev eth0
# ip addr show dev eth0
0: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:bc:de:f1:32:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.5/24 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
# ip route
(empty output, no routes)

This is what NetworkManager does by default, by the way, and then it creates these routes with non-default metric.
Also consider using VRFs in Linux (it seems it's very similar to your end goal). In short, you assign an interface to a VRF, and then any routes associated with that interface (e.g. prefix routes or whatever) will automatically go into that VRF's routing table instead of the main routing table.

That noprefixroute flag seems to do the job. However the "ip addr add" command assigns IP configuration only temporarily to the interface. I use ifcfg interface config files in the network-scripts folder, but I didn't find any way to implement that option in the configuration. Yes, VRF could be the best, but it's hard to implement. The documentation you linked here is just loose, missing of key steps.

Why won't you move from ancient and ugly rhel "ifcfg" files into NetworkManager?
